# Parallel trace signal integrity: Increasing width to match characteristic impedance vs increasing trace gap

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, impedance, impedance-matching, high-speed

Imagine you are routing a large number of single ended high speed traces through a long narrow gap on a PCB. Lets say these are ultra-high speed SD signals, so a 208MHz clock. The traces should be 50mil to match the impedance of the source and receiver.

However, as you are short on space you have to choose one of the two options:

1. Route at the correct width for impedance matching, at a cost of reducing your inter-trace gap to 10mil (i.e. 0.2W), thus greatly increasing crosstalk
2. Route at 10mil width to achieve a larger gap of 50mil (i.e. 5W), at a cost of a significant impedance mismatch.

**Which of these two options is the lesser evil and why? If the answer is somewhere in the middle, how do you evaluate the tradeoff? Does there exist any rules of thumb for prioritising characteristic impedance vs crosstalk?**

Comment: How long is the narrow gap and what are the signal spectrums?

Comment: Lets say the gap is 2" long, and these are signals for an ultra high speed SD card, so around 250MHz max frequency

Comment: Add that to the question please.

Comment: Series or parallel termination resistor? Is that a square (ish) wave of 250 MHz?

Comment: Why not just use 10 mil all the way and a higher value series resistor?

Comment: I was referring to matching the characteristic impedance of the trace to that of the signal, in which case this would not be a solution? (I'm new to high speed design so correct me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: You are using a series terminator and it is that component that defines the impedance. Change if from 50 ohms to circa 100 ohms and route all the way at 10 mil. That's what I'm saying. Please justify why you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Option c: use a thinner dielectric layer so that a 10 mil trace matches 50 ohms.

Comment: You could achieve this by gluing an appropriately sized copper clad board on top of the trace(s) and grounding the copper in a few places. Make the added board thin.